# How to deal with Neural network input data with different length and type

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I'm trying to make use of sensor data from VOC, Humidity, Age, Sampling rate and use them as NN input data. Below are the technical questions I'm struggling to find out.

For each training set, I have 2500 data points for VOC and Humidity. However, for the age and sampling rate, I have only one for each. I'm wondering if it would work to just put 5002(=2500(VOC)+ 2500(hum)+1(age) + 1 (sampling rate)) input data points to the layer.

*Note: sampling rate is in the data set because the VOC and HUM data have different data points for each training set. I reduced the data points by sampling from the original data points. However, I know for sure that timespan does matter.

Please help me out! A good reference is also a huge welcome!